# Why and how is the quota "critial read requests" exceeded when using batchCreateContacts

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I'm programming a contacts export from our database to Google Contacts using the Google People API. I'm programming the requests over URL via Google Apps Script.

The code below - using https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:batchCreateContacts - works for 13 to about 15 single requests, but then Google returns this error message:

> Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Critical read requests (Contact and Profile Reads)' and limit 'Critical read requests (Contact and Profile Reads) per minute per user' of service 'people.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:***'.

For speed I send the request with batches of 10 parallel requests.

I have the following two questions regarding this problem:

1. Why, for *creating* contacts, I would hit a quotum regarding *read* requests?
2. Given the picture link below, why would sending 2 batches of 10 simultaneous requests (more precise: 13 to 15 single requests) hit that quotum limit anyway?
   [quotum limit of 90 read requests per user per minute as displayed on console.cloud.google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et17h.png)

Thank you for any clarification!

Further reading: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/batchCreateContacts

```
  let payloads = [];
  let lengthPayloads;
  let limitPayload = 200;
/*Break up contacts in payload limits*/
  contacts.forEach(function (contact, index) /*contacts is an array of objects for the API*/
    {
      if(!(index%limitPayload))
      {
        lengthPayloads = payloads.push(
          {
            'readMask': "userDefined",
            'sources': ["READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT"],
            'contacts': []
          }
        );
      }
      payloads[lengthPayloads-1]['contacts'].push(contact);
    }
  );
Logger.log("which makes "+payloads.length+" payloads");
  let parallelRequests = [];
  let lengthParallelRequests;
  let limitParallelRequest = 10;
/*Break up payloads in parallel request limits*/
  payloads.forEach(function (payload, index)
    {
      if(!(index%limitParallelRequest))
        lengthParallelRequests = parallelRequests.push([]);
      parallelRequests[lengthParallelRequests-1].push(
        {
          'url': "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:batchCreateContacts",
          'method': "post",
          'contentType': "application/json",
          'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
          'headers': { 'Authorization': "Bearer " + token }, /*token is a token of a single user*/
          'muteHttpExceptions': true
        }
      );
    }
  );
Logger.log("which makes "+parallelRequests.length+" parallelrequests");
  let responses;
  parallelRequests.forEach(function (parallelRequest)
    {
      responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(parallelRequest); /* error occurs here*/
      responses = responses.map(function (response) { return JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); });
      
      responses.forEach(function (response)
        {
          if(response.error)
          {
            Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            throw response;
          }
          else Logger.log("ok");
        }
      );
```

Output of logs:

> which makes 22 payloads
>
> which makes 3 parallelrequests
>
> ok (15 times)
>
> (the error message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Critical read requests (Contact and Profile Reads)' and limit 'Critical read requests (Contact and Profile Reads) per minute per user' of service 'people.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:***'.

There are two types of quotas: project based quotas and user based quotas.  Project based quotas are limits placed upon your project itself.  User based quotes are more like flood protection they limit the number of requests a single user can make over a period of time.

When you send a batch request with 10 requests in it it counts as ten requests not as a single batch request.  If you are trying to run this parallel then you are defiantly going to be overflowing the request per minute per user quota.

Slow down this is not a race.

> Why, for creating contacts, I would hit a quota regarding read requests?

I would chock it up to a bad error message.

> Given the picture link below, why would sending 13 to 15 requests hit that quota limit anyway? ((there are 3 read requests before this code)) quota limit of 90 read requests per user per minute as displayed on console.cloud.google.com

Well you are sending 13 * 10 = 130 per minute that would exceed the request per minute.  There is also no way of knowing how fast your system is running it could be going faster as it will depend upon what else the server is doing at the time it gets your requests what minute they are actually being recorded in.

My advice is to just respect the quota limits and not try to understand why there are to many variables on Googles servers to be able to tack down what exactly a minute is.    You could send 100 requests in 10 seconds and then try to send another 100 in 55 seconds and you will get the error you could also get the error after 65 seconds depend upon when they hit the server and when the server finished processing your initial 100 requests.

Again slow down.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Where can I find the _project based_ quotas? Further, I clarified my question: it hits the limit at the second batch of 10 requests (so, indeed, at the 13th _single_ request). So it doesn't reach the limit of 90 requests... So why does it hit that limit?

Comment: What you don't understands is that if you are getting the error message it is hitting the 90 request quota.  Google isnt lying you need to slow down.   Project based quotas are in the same area that you find all the quotas it just doesn't state "user" on it.

Comment: OK, I believe Google ain't lying :-). But I would like to understand how it counts these requests, because I don't get to 90. Further, I can't find the project based quotas. I'm looking at [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/people.googleapis.com/quotas?project=contactssync-***). Elsewhere on the cloud console I get the message 'Per-user quota usage is not displayed', but nothing about project quota... Anyhow, when a next batch of 10 requests needs to be made, I made the program to wait a minute first. That prevents the error.

Comment: I have been doing this for ten years. There is no way you will figure out how google registers these requests.  You need to consider how fast the server processes your data.  If I am also running something on the same server you are running and my stuff hogs the processer your stuff is going to run slower or faster.  You also need to understand that that the console App is a estimate it is not 100% correct its just a guide.   I also wrote something for flood busting [Flood buster](https://www.daimto.com/google-apis-flood-buster/)   :)

Answer (score 3):

I had raised the same issue in Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199939622).

Seems that the single BatchCreateContacts or BatchUpdateContacts call consumes six (6) "Critical Read Request" quota per request. Still did not get an answer why for *creating/updating* contacts, we are hitting the limit of critical *read* requests.

Comment: Got the response from Google: Mutation operations in People API involve reads to check preconditions and then to return a copy of the resulting data after successful write.