# Google People API people.connections.list has an additional quota

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-people-api

Google's docs for `people.connections.list` say the following:

> The first page of a full sync request has an additional quota. If the quota is exceeded, a 429 error will be returned. This quota is fixed and can not be increased.

Does this mean that after you do the first sync, you're not supposed to trigger the full sync again for a while or you may get blocked by google with status 429, or does this mean something else?

Comment: Have you checked the docs about [Read and Manage Contacts](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/contacts#list_the_users_contacts) by any chance for the quota limits? Apparently, this means that there are only allowed certain number of requests per minute/hour with the People API. According to this [existing SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67686069), the API has 2 types of quotas: project based quotas and user based quotas. For the read limit, it is mainly 90 requests per minute per user.

Comment: @IrvinJayG. I have, but I'm not sure if this has some kind of special quota. Or I might be just misinterpreting the quoted statement.